# GORM dynamically set Mapping

Tags: grails, logging, grails-orm

I'm trying to update the database mapping of an DomainClass to save it in different Tables.
The reason why i'm trying to do so is that I'm working on an AuditListener that dynamicly saves the current Entity also in an Log Table.

I got the Properties and the database Mapping from the Entity. Now i updated the MetaClass of the `RevisionEntity`:

```
Mapping entityMapping = grailsDomainBinder.getMapping(domainClassObject.class) // get Mapping of the Entity Class
entityMapping?.columns?.each{column ->
    String propertyName = column.key
    RevisionEntity.metaClass."${propertyName}" = properties.get(propertyName) ?: null  //add Property to RevisionEntity
}
```

I build an new Mapping, based on the Mapping of the Entity:

```
Mapping newRevisionEntityMapping = new Mapping() // create new Mapping for Revision Entity
newRevisionEntityMapping.versioned = false
newRevisionEntityMapping.tableName = tableName
if(entityMapping?.columns)
    newRevisionEntityMapping.columns?.putAll(entityMapping?.columns) // add column Mapping from origiganal Entity
```

Now I want to set the Mapping to the `RevisionEntity` Class.

Do you have any Suggestions how I can set the Database Mapping of `RevisionEntity`?

Comment: Some of the newer versions of Grails have a built-in event system. I think it would be easier to simply implement `afterInsert()` and `afterUpdate()` in `DomainClass` to generate a say... *DomainClassChanged* event. Then, implement an event listener to log the changed instance to the audit table. Grails has plenty of voodoo already, so if you can avoid adding to it, I think you're future self will thank you.